# What would mermaid population distribution look like?

Tags: humanoid, population, mermaid

What would the population of aquatic humanoids look like? Where would the population cluster? (ie along coasts, in shallower areas, or in warmer waters) Where would the unpopulated "deserts" be?

Comment: That looks like four separate questions, and questions here are supposed to be only one.  Please [edit] your question to ask only one thing, and add more questions to ask about other things.  You might also want to add more detail.

Comment: It is meaningless to speak of the population distribution of cetaceans in general; *some* of them live in shallow waters, some like coastal waters, some congregate in human ports, some never leave the deep ocean, some prefer warmer seas, others thrive in colder waters...

Comment: What do the aquatic humanoids eat?  What type of locations do they need to reproduce?  What are threats to them?  What is their temperature tolerance?  Do they trade with land-based sapients or are they at war with them?  Where is the map that overlays all of the above factors?  Without all of the above details, at a minimum, we cannot answer the question.

Comment: do you know that mermaid is a fictional creature? i'm asking just in case.

Comment: The biggest problem with your question is that it's far too broad. It's like handing us an entire planet's land surface and asking, "where would the humans live?" Well... over time we've come to live almost everywhere, some places more densly than others. So, (a) What's the world-wide population of merfolk? (b) What's their technology level? Given those, we can look at the three-dimensional space of the ocean and start asking questions like, where are the resources they covet the most? ((c) what are those resources?) Where are the warm water currents? The sunny shallows? It's a huge task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is just an oddly phrased single question, rather than four questions. What I *think* you're asking is: How would biomes work for underwater civilisations? That is: where would they live,  where would they  definitely NOT live, how does temperature and depth come into this?

For 'civilised' mermaids, they would quite likely have to live in shallower waters, and warmer would be better, as shallow waters have significantly more life, and warmth also helps. Otherwise they might have trouble getting enough food, which would significantly stall them from creating any sort of civilisation. Organised agriculture is the best way of ensuring food security, and an omnivorous diet could help with this, and it is difficult to cultivate plants with no sunlight. Even with carnivorous mermaids, making fish farms would be much easier in shallow, warmer water.

If you look at this picture, mermaids could live within the orange areas, likely including the area between Canada and Russia, and the area in the northeastern part of canada, although the real prime real estate would be the areas around southeast Asia and Oceania, being very warm, plentiful and also being large expanses of territory. The area around Indonesia and Malaysia would be very nice, with coasts on all sides, along with the area between Papua New Guinea and Australia. There are also good areas around New Zealand.
[image: https://www.flinnsci.ca/ocean-floor-topography-map/ap5226/#variantDetails]
Generally, there is good territory on just about all coasts, particularly those around the equator. Southeast Asia, Oceania and Central America are all good, and many other coastal areas across the map would also be quite nice and very viable. Population centers would most likely be within the equatorial coastal areas due to their higher capacity for food production, but smaller centers could reasonably occur around coastal areas from pole to pole.

It might also be possible for mermaids to live on ocean ridges, shown as the yellow belts in the picture. These areas are good feeding grounds, despite having the same production capacity as the surrounding ocean, as life crowds around the summits. As such, large groups living on ridges could be forced to live nomadically, moving up and down their ridge to allow food to replenish. It should be noted, though, that if the mermaids' advantage over other creatures is their intelligence and/or the ability to manipulate objects with hands, the ridges would make this advantage less relevant and possibly take away their edge over other predators in the area.

Outside of the coasts and ridges, life would be much harder. Not only would the mermaids lose their competitive edge over other predators, as with ridges, food would be scarcer from the get-go. Unless your mermaids are naturally great and better than the competition, these could reasonably serve as 'desert' areas.

Hope that helps! (: